# Creating a Combination chart(line and bar) for same json data using c3js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I want to create a combination chart (line and bar) for same json data so that the line touches the all the bars since datapoints are same.

Here is the code

```
var graphdata=[
{ 'indicator': 'X', 'total': 100 },
            { 'indicator': 'Y', 'total': 200 },
            { 'indicator': 'Z', 'total': 300 }
];
var g1=[
{ 'indicator': 'X', 'total': 150 },
            { 'indicator': 'Y', 'total': 220 },
            { 'indicator': 'Z', 'total': 330 }
];
setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
          data: {
        type: 'line',
        json: g1,
        keys: {
            x: 'indicator',
            value: ['total']
        },

    },
    axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category'
            }
    },
    });
}, 1000);
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        type: 'bar',
        json: graphdata,
        keys: {
            x: 'indicator',
            value: ['total']
        },

    },
    axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'category'
            }
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5
        }
    }
});
```

The output of this is only bar chart,the line chart is not loading.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: i am not getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var data = [
{ 'date': '2015-01-01', 'Dept': null, 'SMV': 3},
{ 'date': '2015-01-02', 'Dept': 1, 'SMV': 4}
];
```

**Example** You separated all the date, the Dept and the SMV data into separate arrays. The way to go here is the following: The data should contain one array of several arrays. The first argument is defined as the key of the dataset. An example dataset looks then like this:

```
var data = [
['date', '2015-01-01', 2015-01-02'],
['Dept', null, 1],
['SMV', 3, 4]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple code below, you can use a simple JSON file as shown below.

```
var graphdata={data1:[100,200,300],data2:[150,220,330]};
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        types: {data1:'spline',
            data2:'bar'
        },
        json: graphdata,
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5
        }
    }
});
```

For more details you can try http://c3js.org/samples/chart_combination.html .